# Python proxy question

Tags: python, proxies

Is it possible to filter all outgoing connections through a HTTPS or SOCKS proxy? I have a script that users various apis & calls scripts that use mechanize/urllib. I'd like to filter every connection through a proxy, setting the proxy in my 'main' script (the one that calls all the apis). Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can put it in your code or take it from the environment.

Look here http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html

```
proxies = {'http': 'http://www.someproxy.com:3128'}
filehandle = urllib.urlopen(some_url, proxies=proxies)
```

Or

```
$ http_proxy="http://www.someproxy.com:3128"
$ export http_proxy
$ python yourScript.py
```

Or

```
$[tsocks][1] yourScript.py
```

Comment: does mechanize/urllib supports socks proxy?

Answer (score 0):

Just like [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlopen) say, `urllib.urlopen()` looks to the system for proxy information, and also takes an optional argument for the proxies to use.

Answer (score 0):

to use tor with mechanize I use tor+polipo.
set polipo to use parent proxy socksParentProxy=localhost:9050 at confing file.
then use

browser.set_proxies({"http": "localhost:8118"})

where 8118 is your polipo port.

so you are using polipo http proxy that uses sock to use tor

hope it helps :)